# What to do about our 10-month-old keeping on shouting?

Tags: infant, discipline, communication

My 10-month-old daughter keeps shouting most of the times until she gets what she needs. At times, she keeps shouting even if we try everything. We haven't tried sign language yet. Has anyone else experienced a similar phase with their kids? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Is crying or fussing? Kids who have yet learned how to talk will always figure out a way to communicate. They'll try different methods until they find one that gets a response that is sufficient for them. The main thing to remember is to talk to her continuously to strengthen her communication and be patient.

Comment: Thanks John!! We have been more diligent about talking to her more frequently when she starts to shout. It is not actually both crying or fussing. Because we have noticed that she is only angry when she shouts. She does that when she needs something that we don't give. But so far in the past week, it has reduced when we talk to her more. Thanks a lot for the tip!!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to each her sign language, so she can make requests that you can understand?

Comment: Expansion of this answer would be helpful. (I know signing is in vogue now, and I've seen it work with grandchild #1. However, I don't think that it works much quite that early. Signing is easier than vocalization initially, but it's still language, and understanding language is a pretty advanced skill. I may be wrong, though.)

Comment: My personal experience is that my kid could sign "milk" and "more" at 11 months.  The baby sign language book we had had testimonials of kids using it earlier.  They might be cherry-picked anecdotes, but they suggest that at least some kids can communicate with specific gestures that young.

Comment: I did say that I didn't think *it works much* quite that early. My granddaughter could sign "milk" at that age as well, and, if I remember correctly, "more". Nothing else, like "I'm bored/frustrated/cold, and I want to be entertained/soothed/dressed more warmly." Ten months is early for real understanding of language, let alone emotional intelligence. Expansion would be helpful to understand how signing might be of *real benefit* to the OP's situation. A flag brought this answer to my attention. Thanks.

Comment: We haven't yet tried the sign language yet. But I'd like to give that also a try. I also feel like it is slightly hard for them to learn how to communicate various feelings at this young age as pointed out by @anongoodnurse. I'll add more comments if I find that useful. Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: My son signed milk at 7 months, and then didn't add another sign until right about 10 months, when he learned 4 more (all done, eat, book, and elephant as far as I remember).  Shortly after age one he had a language explosion and was using about 45 signs in context by the time he started speaking more than a handful of words.  I feel like it actually did decrease his frustration, because he was able to ask for his needs, but more importantly (to him at least) /share his interests/.  Many of his early signs were things he wanted to talk about, toys and animals and vehicles, vs needs.